# Why pydevd.settrace() called in the global scope of a module doesn't work?

Tags: python, pydev, remote-debugging, pycharm, paster

I'm using PyCharm 3.1.1 IDE, Pyramid 1.4.5 web framework and I test my web app using web server that comes with PasteScript 1.7.5 package.
I placed `pydevd.settrace()` call in the global scope of middleware.py module but this does not work – connection to debug server is made (I see `Connected to pydev debugger (build 133.881)` in the console inside PyCharm) but execution is stuck in this line. This is code that I'm using:

```
import pydevd
pydevd.settrace('my.host.at.local.domain', port=21000, suspend=False, stdoutToServer=False, stderrToServer=False)
```

In middleware.py module there's `make_app` function which is registered in setup.py of my project as an entry point for Paste like this:

```
setup(
    (...)
    entry_points="""
        [paste.app_factory]
        main = myapp.config.middleware:make_app
        (...)
    """
)
```

Moving `pydevd.settrace()` call into `make_app` function solves the problem i.e. connection is being made to the debug server and subsequent code is being executed.

However, I would like to know why placing `pydevd.settrace()` call in the global scope of middleware.py module does not work?